# How to query the most recent 5 records in mongoose based on the most recent Ids of reference property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following data stored in mongodb. I want to perform a complex query. I want to get  the last 5 messages of the most recent 10 conversationId.

How can I do that?

```
[ { _id: 5e7bb4c699aa010ca9bfeed4,
payload: 'Message 1 from A to B',
sender: 'A',
reciever: 'B',
conversationId: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
time: 2020-03-25T19:45:10.029Z,
__v: 0 },

{ _id: 5e7bb52a99aa010ca9bfeed5,
payload: 'Message 1 from B to A',
sender: 'B',
reciever: 'A',
conversationId: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
time: 2020-03-25T19:46:50.171Z,
__v: 0 },

{ _id: 5e7bb57f99aa010ca9bfeed6,
payload: 'Message 2 from A to B'
sender: 'A',
reciever: 'B',
conversationId: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
time: 2020-03-25T19:48:15.965Z,
__v: 0 },

{ _id: 5e7bde6e86caad11b4a7a2a0,
payload: 'This is messages from B to A',
sender: 'B',
reciever: 'A',
conversationId: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
time: 2020-03-25T22:42:54.017Z,
__v: 0 },

{ _id: 5e7bb68f99aa010ca9bfeeda,
payload: 'Message 1 from B to C',
sender: 'B',
reciever: 'C',
conversationId: 5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9,
time: 2020-03-25T19:52:47.243Z,
__v: 0 },

{ _id: 5e7bb6d599aa010ca9bfeedb,
payload: 'Message 1 from C to B',
sender: 'C',
reciever: 'B',
conversationId: 5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9,
time: 2020-03-25T19:53:57.805Z,
__v: 0 },
```

I tried the following query but it is not working

```js
const qmessages = await messages
  .find({
    conversationId: {
      $in: mapedId,
    },
  })
  .or([
    {
      sender: req.user.fullname,
    },
    {
      reciever: req.user.fullname,
    },
  ])
  .sort({
    conversationId: 1,
    time: 1,
  });
```

where `mapedId is the an array of conversationsID`.
if I add .limit to my query it doesnot work as expected

Comment: Do you want last 5 messages of each of those conversations or you want overall last 5 amongst given converrsationIds?

Comment: What i want is the last 5 messages of each conversationID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first match your conversations by using $in operator, then sort by time, then group by conversationId pushing the root docs, and use $slice aggregation to limit the messages.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      conversationId: {
        $in: [
          "5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12",
          "5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      time: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$conversationId",
      messages: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      messages: {
        $slice: [
          "$messages",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XT-9qjcLuOc)

Comment: First of all thank you alot. Thats what I really wanted. Just a quick question does this method query all messages under a certain conversationId then filter the 5 messages or it does query latest 5 message under a certain conversationId. I am asking this because I am little bit worried about the performance. Once again, Thank you very much

Comment: @Ahmed we have already a match stage that filters documents, so it is unlikely this query will have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, you want recent 5 messages of every `conversationId`. Rigtht?

If yes, this would be the answer. I hope this would help you getting your required answer.

```
const qmessages = await messages.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      conversationId: "5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2 //You can specify number of records to be returned here
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      time: -1
    }
  }
])
```

You can also visit this page where you will get to see working example.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/9YM0I_UJVc2

Comment: Can $match take an array of conversationids

Comment: Wouldnot this just query the last 2 records with conversationId: "5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12", What if i want the last 2 records of each conversationId for example(""5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12", "5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9")

Comment: Yes, match can take array of conversationIds but have no idea on how to get your required answer. it'll take time for me to analyze your requirement.